# Python POST fastq file

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, file-format, fastq

I'm wondering how to post a fastq file/python object via requests.

```
from Bio import SeqIO
seqs = SeqIO.parse("/path/to/seqfile.fastq", "fastq")
```

I use Bio to decode a fastq file. I want to send either the entire fastq file, and then create the object at server side, or then, post the object and decode the object at server side.

Best would be to send the entire fastq file, I know for a text file you would do:

```
files = {'upload_file': ('foobar.txt', open('file.txt','rb'), 'text/x-spam')}

r = requests.post(url, files=files)
```

So the basic question is, what is the header for fastq files?

Like, text : **'text/x-spam'**, json : **'application/json'**, etc.

Comment: It does not looks like IANA assigned anything to that format (http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml), so I will go with `text/plain`

Comment: How will I download the file server side?

Comment: I also think this wouldn't work. When I tried this I get: `AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'content'`

Comment: This is a different question. But `download` and `server side` are not usually in the same sentence.

Answer (score 0):

What do you run that gives you the `AttributeError` mentioned in the comments?

It's not entirely clear from your question if this is what you are doing, but you shouldn't to try upload the results of `SeqIO.parse` as a file. That returns an iterator of file objects, which you could serialise and decode with custom JSON encoders/decoders if you wanted to send the objects over HTTP as JSON.

Alternatively you could just send the text content of the file in the upload and then save it to disk/use a textwrapper and parse with Biopython.

An example Flask endpoint that accepts a FASTQ file, then parses the content with a `StringIO` wrapper would be:

```
from io import StringIO

from flask import Flask, request
from Bio import SeqIO

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def simple_upload():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if 'file' not in request.files:
            print('No file part')
            return 'Error', 500
        file = request.files['file']
        if file.filename == '':
            print('No selected file')
            return 'Error', 500
        if file:
            for s in SeqIO.parse(StringIO(file.read().decode('utf-8')), 'fastq'):
                print(s.id)
            print(file.content_type)
    return 'OK', 200
```

If you run:

```
import requests
files = {'file': ('my_test_file.fastq', open('my_test_file.fastq', 'rb'), 'text/plain')}
url='http://127.0.0.1:5000/'
r = requests.post(url, files=files)
```

Then your server side will successfully print out the IDs of the sequences in your uploaded file.

That's just a simple proof of concept that this works, you could do whatever you like with the uploaded file - save it to disk, process the contents, display the contents etc.